# How can I make a minimal Debian installer USB for both UEFI / BIOS systems?

Tags: usb, debian, bios, uefi

I want to make a Debian installer USB drive using the netinst linux and initrd images. For installing from CD, there is an image called `mini.iso` which I can directly burn it into a CD or write it into an USB, but it doesn't work on UEFI systems because the image does not have \boot\efi\bootx64.efi in it.

How can I make such an image, preferably using only linux, initrd and the minimal number of file in order to boot the system (including the efi boot program)?

Comment: Use Rufus which add the needed EFI files to that bootable flash drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just confirmed that by writing the latest stretch mini.iso image into a disk it can boot in both UEFI and BIOS mode in VirtualBox.